# Ошибка Can't resolve all parameters for e: (?, ?, [object Object])

Tags: javascript, typescript, angular

```
ts component
import { Component, OnInit } from "@angular/core";
import { OrganisationService } from "../organisation.service.ts";
import { UserService } from "../../user/user.service.ts";
import { ng1RootScope } from "../../ajs-upgraded-providers/rootScope.ts";


@Component({
    selector: 'app-dropdown-organisation-list.component',
    templateUrl: 'assets/components/organisation/dropdown-organisation-list/dropdown-organisation-list.component.html',
})

export class DropdownOrganisationListComponent implements OnInit {

    organisations = [];
    showDropdown = false;
    constructor(
        private organisationService: OrganisationService,
        private userService: UserService,
        private rootScope: ng1RootScope,
    ) {}


    ngOnInit() {
    this.userService.getOrganisation().then(() => {
        this.prepareDataForView();
    });

    document.body.addEventListener('click', this.closeDropdown.bind(this));
    document.body.addEventListener('touchstart', this.closeDropdown.bind(this));

    this.rootScope.on('reloadOrganisationList', () => {
        this.prepareDataForView();
    });
}

    closeDropdown(event) {
    if (!(event.target).parents('dropdown-organisation-list').length) {
        this.showDropdown = false;
    }
}

    toggleDropdown() {
    this.showDropdown = !this.showDropdown;
}

    loginIntoOrganisation(orgId) {
    const userPermissions = this.userService.getPermissions();
    let isLoginFromTempOrg = false;
    Object.keys(userPermissions).map(permission => {
        if (permission === 'temp.organisation' || permission === 'temp.agent') {
            isLoginFromTempOrg = true;
        }
    });
    const redirectUrl = isLoginFromTempOrg ? '/organisation' : null;
    this.organisationService.loginIntoOrganisation(orgId, redirectUrl);
}

    private prepareDataForView() {
    Promise.all([
        this.organisationService.getOrganisationList(),
        this.organisationService.getUserGroupsInAllOrganisations(),
    ])
        .then(response => {
            this.organisations = response[0].data
                .filter(organisation => {
                    const isCurrentOrg = organisation.id === organisation.id;
                    if (!organisation.isTempOrg && !isCurrentOrg) {
                        return organisation;
                    }
                })
                .map(organisation => {
                    organisation.groups = [];
                    const userOrganisationsGroups = response[1].data;
                    for (let i = 0; i < userOrganisationsGroups.length; i++) {
                        if (userOrganisationsGroups[i].orgId === organisation.id) {
                            organisation.groups.push(userOrganisationsGroups[i].title);
                        }
                    }
                    return organisation;
                });
        })
}
}
modul
'use strict';

import {NgModule} from '@angular/core';
import {CommonModule} from '@angular/common';
import {FormsModule} from "@angular/forms";
import {downgradeComponent} from "@angular/upgrade/static";

import OrganisationContractsModule from './contracts/contracts.module';
import TerminateContractModule from './terminate-contract/terminate.module';
import {TransferAgreementModule, TransferAgreementModuleNg1} from './transferagreement/transfer-agreement.module.ts';

import {TaxpayerCommonModule} from "../taxpayer-common/taxpayer-common.module.ts";
import OrganisationService from './organisation.service.ts';
import {OrganisationListComponent} from './organisation-list/organisation-list.component.ts';
import {OrganisationsPageComponent} from './organisations-page/organisations-page.component.ts';
import { DropdownOrganisationListComponent } from './dropdown-organisation-list/dropdown-organisation-list.component.ts';
import {OrganisationEditPageComponent} from "./organisation-edit-page/organisation-edit-page.component.ts";
import {OrganisationFormComponent} from "./organisation-edit-page/organisation-form/organisation-form.component.ts";
import {EntrepreneurFormComponent} from "./organisation-edit-page/entrepreneur-form/entrepreneur-form.component.ts";
import {ReturnUserPageComponent} from "./terminate-contract/return-user/return-user.component.ts";


const OrganisationModuleNg1 = angular
    .module('taxpayer.components.organisation', [
        OrganisationContractsModule,
        TerminateContractModule,
        TransferAgreementModuleNg1,
    ])
    .service('OrganisationService', OrganisationService)
    .directive('appOrganisationsPage', downgradeComponent({component: OrganisationsPageComponent}) as angular.IDirectiveFactory)
    .directive('appOrganisationEditPage', downgradeComponent({component: OrganisationEditPageComponent}) as angular.IDirectiveFactory)
    .directive ('appDropdownOrganisationList', downgradeComponent({component: DropdownOrganisationListComponent}) as angular.IDirectiveFactory)
    .directive('appReturnUserPage', downgradeComponent({component: ReturnUserPageComponent}) as angular.IDirectiveFactory)
    .config(['$routeProvider', function ($routeProvider) {
        $routeProvider
            .when('/organisation', {
                template: '<app-organisations-page></app-organisations-page>',
            })
            .when('/organisation/edit', {
                template: '<app-organisation-edit-page></app-organisation-edit-page>',
            })
            .when('/organisation/new-org/main-info', {
                template: '<org-registration-main-info environment="\'cabinet\'"></org-registration-main-info>',
            })
            .when('/return-user', {
                template: '<app-return-user-page></app-return-user-page>',
            })
    }])
    .name;

@NgModule({
    imports: [
        CommonModule,
        TransferAgreementModule,
        TaxpayerCommonModule,
        FormsModule,
    ],
    declarations: [
        OrganisationListComponent,
        OrganisationsPageComponent,
        OrganisationEditPageComponent,
        OrganisationFormComponent,
        EntrepreneurFormComponent,
        ReturnUserPageComponent,
        DropdownOrganisationListComponent,

    ],
    providers: [],
    entryComponents: [
        OrganisationsPageComponent,
        OrganisationEditPageComponent,
        ReturnUserPageComponent,
    ],
})
class OrganisationModule {
}

export {OrganisationModuleNg1, OrganisationModule}
```

Comment: И чего вы хотите? Хотите, что бы мы проанализировали весь ваш листинг? Могли бы хотя бы залить в онлайн-песочницу...

Comment: @Artem я не понимаю где связь между angularjs и angular и что вы пытаетесь сделать, и зачем вообще этот велосипед с гибридностью

Comment: @overthesanity это старый проект,его приходится переписывать на новый angular.Я не понимаю ошибку, и не представляю как ее решить.

Comment: @Artem так как по вашему кто-то способен разобраться в том что вы привели в 1 куче? :)